# what is the difference between defaule and console logins in NX-OS switch?

Tags: authentication, switch-statement

For aaa authentication configuration on NX-OS switch , what is the difference between default and console logins ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

console authentication is for serial console port, default is for administration via network